# Being Careful with my new Hard Drive Docking Station

Tags: hard-drive, dock

I feel weird with plug-and-play HDD's.  It just seems unnatural to be turning the thing on and off, switching the USB over, etc.

I'm using it in a fairly variable environment - it will be connecting to different computers constantly (perhaps 4 or 5 times a day), not to mention the actual HDD is switched fairly often, as well.

With this in mind, I'm a bit scared.  Am I going to corrupt a drive doing this?  This is my dock, here:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00A2WMPOA/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A2WMPOA)

What do I need to do when switching out HDDs and what do I need to do when switching computers?

Comment: It's not all that scary, read about [eSATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA).

Comment: I would be more scared of dropping the drive once out of the dock!

Comment: @ta.speot.is So are you saying that I could basically just pull the things out while running and just switch drives without any turning on/off of devices?

Comment: @Xan - Is this being used with Windows? Can you see the drive in "Safely remove"?

Comment: If its based on eSATA, sure. Just "safely remove" the device in Windows first, if you can. If not, read the instructions for your dock and see if it has specific advice either way.

Comment: @ta.speot.is You should post that as an answer so that I can accept it.